# Cassandra TTL is expired still data is not deleted from disk

Tags: cassandra, ttl

We have set TTL for each table in cassandra cluster,TTL is set for 48 hours ,but still disks are getting full and sstables data is not getting deleted,the default gc_grace_seconds is 10 days .

Comment: data is deleted only during compaction...

Comment: @AlexOtt is correct.  Also, I'm unsure what the actual question is here.  Are you asking "why" this is happening, or "what" you should do about it?